# Installing RedHawk on CentOS7

Tags: redhawksdr

CentOS 7 has been out nearly a year now.  Has anyone installed RedHawk on CentOS 7?  I do not see binaries available on the RedHawk download page.  Has anyone successfully built it from sources?  Are there issues?

I also do not find RPMs for omniORB-servers or omniORB-devel.  Has anyone succeeded in building these on CentOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terry, Ive built redhawk yum repositories for CentOS7 which you can find below however a few things to note:

1. As Ryan pointed out, currently redhawk only officially supports CentOS6 and Ubuntu, these rpms are ***not*** offically built and distributed by redhawksdr.org. However if you do have any issues with them or find any problems please feel free to feed this back to me.
2. These RPMs were originally built prior to Fedora packaing omniORB 4.2. To account for this, I built and packaged omniORB 4.1 for CentOS7 which is the same version redhawk uses on CentOS6.  My omniORB41 package and EPEL's omniORB (v4.2) package conflict so you cannot have the epel package installed. I have not tested redhawk with omniORB 4.2 which is why I packaged the older 4.1 version.

You can find the 1.10.1 yum repository here:

http://yum.axiosengineering.com/redhawk/1.10.1/el7/x86_64/

I will hopefully soon update with 1.10.2

You will also need the dependency repository here:

http://yum.axiosengineering.com/redhawk-deps/1.10/el7/x86_64/

To install via yum, create the file /etc/yum.repos.d/redhawk_axios.repo

With the following text:

```
[redhawk]
name=UNOFFICIAL REDHAWK 1.10.1
baseurl=http://yum.axiosengineering.com/redhawk/1.10.1/el7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[redhawk-deps]
name=UNOFFICIAL REDHAWK DEPS
baseurl=http://yum.axiosengineering.com/redhawk-deps/1.10/el7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then from a terminal:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install redhawk* frontendInterfaces* bulkioInterfaces* GPP-*
```

Comment: Thanks, I give them a try

Answer (score 1):

REDHAWK is only officially supported on CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 14.04.  omniORB should now be in Fedora EPEL 7:

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/omniORB

Comment: The RedHawk manual only states support for CentOS 5, 6 and RHEL.  Does it really support Ubuntu 14.04?  or at least is it know to run well under Ubuntu?  I am interested in running it on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Redhawk 2.3.0 on Centos 7.9 by following these instructions https://redhawksdr.org/2.3.0/manual/installation/

The exact commands I used:

```sh
mkdir ~/Documents/Redhawk
cd ~/Documents/Redhawk
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
wget https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.3.0/redhawk-yum-2.3.0-el7-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf redhawk-yum-2.3.0-el7-x86_64.tar.gz
cd redhawk-2.3.0-el7-x86_64
sudo yum install -y redhawk-release*.rpm
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/redhawk.repo
```

Content of /etc/yum.repos.d/redhawk.repo:

```
[redhawk]
name=REDHAWK Repository
baseurl=file:///home/causer/Documents/Redhawk/redhawk-2.3.0-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhawk
```

Once the file is saved (ctrl+x, y), in the same directory as before:

```sh
sudo yum groupinstall "REDHAWK Runtime"
. /etc/profile.d/redhawk.sh
. /etc/profile.d/redhawk-sdrroot.sh
sudo /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G redhawk causer
sudo nano /etc/omniORB.cfg
sudo $OSSIEHOME/bin/cleanomni
sudo systemctl enable omniNames.service
sudo systemctl enable omniEvents.service
Copy redhawk.desktop to the desktop and run it (rpm -qpl on the redhawk-ide-xyz.rpm its near the bottom of the list)
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc
```